# How to pass a variable from pyqt to .py file and execute it on button click?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I want to pass a filename from this pyqt4 app to another .py file and execute the respective .py file when button is clicked.

**GUI.py**

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import subprocess

class QDataViewer(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
            self.uploadButton = QtGui.QPushButton('UPLOAD', self)
            self.uploadButton.setGeometry(300, 20, 80, 35)
            self.Button = QtGui.QPushButton('Key', self)
            self.Button.setGeometry(90, 150, 180, 35)
            self.connect(self.uploadButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.open)
            self.Button.clicked.connect(lambda:self.run('My_file.py'))
    def open (self):
        self.filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', "", "*.txt")
        return self.filename # I want THIS VARIABLE to be passed to another python file.

    def run(self, path):
        subprocess.call(['python',path])
```

**My_File.py**

```
textdoc = open(filename_from_GUI(self.filename), 'r').read()
By Using 'textdoc' relevant code(function) here
```

I want to know how to **first** pass **self.filename** variable from pyqt class to another file and **then** Execute the My_file.py when **self.Button** is clicked in GUI.py

Comment: You can have function `myFunc (filename)` in `My_File.py` and have the value passed to it.

Comment: thanks for replying , but how to pass the variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [command line arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv). Change the `run` function to this:

```
def run(self, path):
    subprocess.call(['python',path,self.filename])
```

to pass the file name as a command line argument. In file My_file.py you can then access it like so:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[1])
```